# Django - Use a property as a foreign key

Tags: python, django, database-design

The database of my app is populated and kept syncd with external data sources. I have an abstract model from which all the models of my Django 2.2 app derives, defined as follow:

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    # Auto-generated by Django, but included in this example for clarity.
  # id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    ORIGIN_SOURCEA = '1'
    ORIGIN_SOURCEB = '2'
    ORIGIN_CHOICES = [
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEA, 'Source A'),
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEB, 'Source B'),
    ]
    object_origin = models.IntegerField(choices=ORIGIN_CHOICES)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()

class A(CommonModel):
    some_stuff = models.CharField()

class B(CommonModel):
    other_stuff = models.IntegerField()
    to_a_fk = models.ForeignKey("myapp.A", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(CommonModel):
    more_stuff = models.CharField()
    b_m2m = models.ManyToManyField("myapp.B")
```

The `object_id` field **can't be set as unique** since each data source I use in my app may have an object with an `object_id = 1`. Hence the need to track down the origin of the object, by the field `object_origin`.

Unfortunately, Django's ORM doesn't support more-than-one columns foreign keys.

### Problem

Whilst keeping the auto-generated primary key in the database (`id`), I would like to make my foreign key and many-to-many relations happen on both `object_id` and `object_origin` fields instead of the primary key `id`.

### What I've tried

I thought about doing something like this:

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    # Auto-generated by Django, but included in this example for clarity.
  # id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    ORIGIN_SOURCEA = '1'
    ORIGIN_SOURCEB = '2'
    ORIGIN_CHOICES = [
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEA, 'Source A'),
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEB, 'Source B'),
    ]
    object_origin = models.IntegerField(choices=ORIGIN_CHOICES)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()

    def _get_composed_object_origin_id(self):
        return f"{self.object_origin}:{self.object_id}"
    composed_object_origin_id = property(_get_composed_object_origin_id)

class A(CommonModel):
    some_stuff = models.CharField()

class B(CommonModel):
    other_stuff = models.IntegerField()
    to_a_fk = models.ForeignKey("myapp.A", to_field="composed_object_origin_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But Django complains about it:

`myapp.B.to_a_fk: (fields.E312) The to_field 'composed_object_origin_id' doesn't exist on the related model 'myapp.A'.`

And it sounds legit, Django excepted the filed given to `to_field` to be a database field. But there is no need to add a new field to my `CommonModel` since `composed_object_type_id` is built uisng two non-nullable fields...

Comment: Interesting idea, but this looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) from my perspective... **Why** do you need this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment in the other answer that object_id is not unique but it is unique in combination with object_type, so could you use a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in the metaclass? i.e

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    object_type = models.IntegerField()
    object_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("object_type", "object_id"),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have / Can you set the `unique` attribute on the `object_id` field?

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    object_type = models.IntegerField()
    object_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

If this does´nt work, I would change the field type to an `uuid` field:

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    object_type = models.IntegerField()
    object_uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `object_id` can't be set as unique because there are cases were it is not unique.
Actually, in the external data source that provides me the data I use in my app, the primary key is made up with two fields: `object_type` and `object_id`.

Comment: If `object_id` isn’t unique, you shouldn’t create an foreign key. This could cause errors in the database and you don’t want that. If you don’t want to use the pk instead, you could also manage the ralationship on yourself in the built-in `models.Model` functions.

Comment: Well, `object_type` and `object_id` together are guaranteed to be unique. But `object_id` alone isn't.

Comment: Here you can find a pip package to create a Foreign Key Constraint to a compound (two keys): 
https://django-composite-foreignkey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Unfortunately Django 2.1+ apps aren't supported and it seems like this library is not actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioned in your question as " **Unfortunately, Django's ORM doesn't support more-than-one columns foreign keys** ".

Yes, Django is not provide that type of support because Django has more reliable than we think :)

So, Django provide one meta option to overcome this type of problem and that option is `unique_together`.

You can provide Sets of field names that, taken together, must be unique, in your case...

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    # Auto-generated by Django, but included in this example for clarity.
    # id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
    serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    ORIGIN_SOURCEA = '1'
    ORIGIN_SOURCEB = '2'
    ORIGIN_CHOICES = [
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEA, 'Source A'),
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEB, 'Source B'),
    ]
    object_origin = models.IntegerField(choices=ORIGIN_CHOICES)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()

    class meta:
        unique_together = [['object_origin', 'object_id']]
```

You can provide list of list, sets of set or simple list, simple set to `unique_together` option of `class meta:`.

Yes but Django said that...

> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together.
>
> unique_together may be deprecated in the future.

You can add `UniqueConstraint` instead of `unique_together` in same `class meta:` in your case you can write as below...

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    # Auto-generated by Django, but included in this example for clarity.
    # id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
    serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    ORIGIN_SOURCEA = '1'
    ORIGIN_SOURCEB = '2'
    ORIGIN_CHOICES = [
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEA, 'Source A'),
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEB, 'Source B'),
    ]
    object_origin = models.IntegerField(choices=ORIGIN_CHOICES)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()

    class meta:
        constraints = [ models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['object_origin', 'object_id'], name='unique_object')]
```

So, the best practice is to use `constraints` option instead of `unique_together` of `class meta:`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the composed object origin ID a field (`composed_object_origin_id`) that is updated on `save` and used as the `to_field`.

```py
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    ORIGIN_SOURCEA = "1"
    ORIGIN_SOURCEB = "2"
    ORIGIN_CHOICES = [
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEA, "Source A"),
        (ORIGIN_SOURCEB, "Source B"),
    ]
    object_origin = models.IntegerField(choices=ORIGIN_CHOICES)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    composed_object_origin_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.composed_object_origin_id = f"{self.object_origin}:{self.object_id}"

        # Just in case you use `update_fields`, force inclusion of the composed object origin ID.
        # NOTE: There's definitely a less error-prone way to write this `if` statement but you get
        # the gist. e.g., this does not handle passing `update_fields=None`.
        if "update_fields" in kwargs:
            kwargs["update_fields"].append("composed_object_origin_id")

        super().save(**kwargs)


class A(CommonModel):
    some_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=1)


class B(CommonModel):
    other_stuff = models.IntegerField()
    to_a_fk = models.ForeignKey(
        "myapp.A", to_field="composed_object_origin_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```